# Can this script be edited to create a "shotgun" type spread when firing? [Top down shooter]

Tags: physics, shooter

I have this code and I'd like to add a shotgun to the game by slightly modifying the code. I've looked online for any example but everything I find is for FPS not a TDS.

```
void Shoot ()
{
    timer = 0f;

    gunAudio.Play ();

    gunLight.enabled = true;

    gunParticles.Stop ();
    gunParticles.Play ();

    gunLine.enabled = true;
    gunLine.SetPosition (0, transform.position);

    shootRay.origin = transform.position;
    shootRay.direction = transform.forward;

    if (Physics.Raycast (shootRay, out shootHit, range, shootableMask))
    {
        EnemyHealth enemyHealth = shootHit.collider.GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();
        if(enemyHealth != null)
        {
            enemyHealth.TakeDamage (damagePerShot, shootHit.point);
        }
        gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootHit.point);
    }
    else
    {
        gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootRay.origin + shootRay.direction * range);
    }
}
```

I have a basic understanding of most of this code. I don't quite understand how shootRay.direction understands transform.forward means always the front of player. As DMGregory stated adding a variable of some sort that runs through a for loop firing multiple different angles (or simply different coordinates if making angle rays is over my head) is the route I first thought of but I cannot find a way to implement it. I'm having issues with understanding how to manipulate ray coordinates because they cannot be changed by floats which is the extent of my current knowledge of problem solving.

Comment: In order to give you the help you need it would be helpful to know how much of this code you understand.

Comment: It seems all you'd need to do is add a random offset to `shootRay.direction` and fire multiple times with different offsets. How much of that do you know how to do already?

Comment: I think you use Unity. So, you can make a new object, add the script to it and change some properties.

Comment: @Philipp I have a basic understanding of most of it. I don't quite understand how shootRay.direction understands transform.forward means always the front of player.


 As DMGregory stated adding a variable of some sort that runs through a for loop firing multiple different angles (or simply different coordinates if making angle rays is over my head) is the route I first thought of but I cannot find a way to implement it. I'm having issues with understanding how to manipulate ray coordinates because they cannot be changed by floats which is the extent of my current knowledge of problem solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "realistic" way to handle this is to just change the `shootRay.direction` vector.

```
for (var i = 0; i< pellets; i++){
    var offset = Random.insideUnitSphere * accuracy;
    shootRay.direction = transform.forward + offset;
    //then your raycast
}
```

`Random.insideUnitSphere` will give you a random point inside a unit sphere.

`accuracy` should be a small float value to lessen the effect of insideUnitSphere

When `transform.forward` is added to the offset it will change they x, y and z coordinate for the direction

The easiest way is simply to reduce the damage based on the distance away the target is.

edit: Didn't notice what you said about examples for FPS. Why do feel like handling it different than a FPS?

Edit 2: You can set `offset.y=0` to make sure there is no spread.

Comment: This code seems to be working except some of the shots are going above the enemies. I believe it is because the change in the y coordinates in Random.insideUnitSphere. The game is a TDS so there is no Y axis aiming. 

 On a hunch I tried Random.insideUnitCircle, but realized that not only doesn't run, but that is x, y coords. Is there a way to change this?


Thank you very much, you're a big help.

Comment: @user3167069 Just set `shotRay.direction.y = 0` before raycasting.

Comment: @DMGregory that is assuming that `shootRay.origin.y == 0`. setting it to `shootRay.origin.y` ensures that it is at the same point in y.

Comment: @AdamP No, that's incorrect. `Ray.direction`, as the name implies, is a direction, or relative offset. It is not a second point on the ray. So a ray with a `direction.y = 0` travels along an x-z plane passing through whatever point `origin` describes.

Comment: You are correct. I am changing it back.

Comment: I am getting an error on that line stating I should store it in a variable. I am not very familiar with var at this point. I have it like

    for (var i = 0; i < pellets; i++)
        {var offset = Random.insideUnitSphere * accuracy;
        shootRay.direction = transform.forward + offset;
        shootRay.direction.y = 0;

I also tried shootRay.direction.y == 0 and shootRay.origin.y == 0.
 
 
 
Edit: I cannot figure out how to format code in comment section.

Comment: It seems to only allow changes to all coordinates of the ray if they are together (x, y, z). I have tried changing only x and z in the code and it throws the same error. That Assets/Scripts/Player/PlayerShooting.cs(74,34): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Ray.direction'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Comment: Try setting `offset.y =0` instead. That should work. If it does I'll change my answer.

Comment: Changing to offset.y = 0 worked. Thank you for the help and patience.